# Protractor time out angular 6

Tags: angular, protractor, end-to-end

I'm using Protractor for e2e test in Angular 6 project. currently I'm using two browsers executing `browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);` to test a WebRTC app.

The problem is protractor fails with Time out waiting  for element with locator

My test

```
describe('Two browsers: ', () => {
  const OVC = new MyObject();
  const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  beforeEach(() => {

    browser.get('#/page1');
  });
  it('both users should can type messages and reveive its', () => {
    const browser2 = OVC.openNewBrowserInTheSameRoom(browser);
    browser2.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(browser.element(by.css('#navChatButton'))), 5000);
    browser.element(by.css('#navChatButton')).click();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(browser.element(by.css('#messageInput input'))), 5000);
    browser.element(by.css('#messageInput input')).click();
    browser.element(by.css('#messageInput input')).sendKeys('New Message User 1');
    OVC.pressEnter(browser);

    browser2.wait(EC.presenceOf(browser2.element(by.css('#navChatButton'))), 5000);
    browser2.element(by.css('#navChatButton')).click();

    expect(OVC.getMessageList(browser2).count()).toEqual(1);
    browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf(OVC.getChatInput(browser2)), 5000);
    OVC.getChatInput(browser2).click();
    OVC.getChatInput(browser2).sendKeys('Message User 2');
    OVC.pressEnter(browser2);
    expect(OVC.getMessageList(browser).count()).toEqual(2);
    OVC.closeSession(browser2);
  });
});
```

The error is :

```
- Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an
> Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details:
> https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
> While waiting for an element with locator - Locator: By(CSS selector,
> #navChatButton)
```

But my element (#navChatButton) exist in the DOM.
What I'm being wrong?

**Edit:** If i remove the `browser.wait` the test works. So why `browser.wait` doesn't work with angular?

Comment: ave you tried increasing the timeout period to something like 30 seconds to see what happens?

Comment: Does `browser2` works with `.wait`?

Comment: @demouser123  Yes and the result is the same. Timeout waiting for element

Comment: @Oleksii it really strange, in another test cases the `browser.wait` works in the two browsers but in this case, it doesn't works

Comment: My suggestion is to remove all angular waiters :)